# Could not build Objective c Module

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, xcode8

i was making a xcode project with swift and it was working fine but suddenly it started giving me this error.

> Could not build Objective C Module 'Foundation'
>
> /Users/admin/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSNotification.h:17:4: Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol

Even when i create a new project and do nothing but just build it, this error is shown. The project is not built. When i click on the error message, it leads me to this file ***NSNotification.h***

Here are the contents of this file

```
/*  NSNotification.h
Copyright (c) 1994-2016, Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
*/

#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

typedef NSString *NSNotificationName NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM;

@class NSString, NSDictionary, NSOperationQueue;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

/****************   Notifications   ****************/

@interface NSNotification : NSObject <NSCopying, NSCoding>

id@property (nullable, readonly, retain) id object;
@property (nullable, readonly, copy) NSDictionary *userInfo;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSNotificationName)name object:(nullable    id)object userInfo:(nullable NSDictionary *)userInfo NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder     NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end

@interface NSNotification (NSNotificationCreation)

+ (instancetype)notificationWithName:(NSNotificationName)aName object:      (nullable id)anObject;
+ (instancetype)notificationWithName:(NSNotificationName)aName object:        (nullable id)anObject userInfo:(nullable NSDictionary *)aUserInfo;

- (instancetype)init /*NSUIImagePNGRepresentation_UNAVAILABLE*/;    /* do     not invoke; not a valid initializer for this class */

@end

/****************   Notification Center ****************/

@interface NSNotificationCenter : NSObject {
@package
void *_impl;
void *_callback;
void *_pad[11];
}

#if FOUNDATION_SWIFT_SDK_EPOCH_AT_LEAST(8)
@property (class, readonly, strong) NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter;

- (void)addObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector name:(nullable      NSNotificationName)aName object:(nullable id)anObject;
#endif

- (void)postNotification:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSNotificationName)aName object:(nullable  id)anObject;
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSNotificationName)aName object:(nullable id)anObject userInfo:(nullable NSDictionary *)aUserInfo;

-     (void)removeObserver:(id)observer;
- (void)removeObserver:(id)observer name:(nullable NSNotificationName)aName object:(nullable id)anObject;

- (id <NSObject>)addObserverForName:(nullable NSNotificationName)name object:(nullable id)obj queue:(nullable NSOperationQueue *)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification *note))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
// The return value is retained by the system, and should be held onto by the caller in
// order to remove the observer with removeObserver: later, to stop observation.

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Please help me through this. I will be very grateful for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in NSNotification.h looks like it's been modified:

```
id@property (nullable, readonly, retain) id object;
```

Delete the `id` at the front of that line and try to recompile. That should fix it.